# How to disable the mouse wheel scrolling in mpv?

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel, mpv

The wheel has eventually become "loose" with all mice I've owned and can be scrolled by accident. In mpv the wheel controls the video position.

from [the documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#key-names):

> `WHEEL_*`
>
> Mouse wheels (typically).

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

If you click the search bar on the bottom left (next to the Windows start button) you'll then want to type in `%appdata%` and click enter on your keyboard.

This will bring you into your `AppData/Roaming` folder. Once you've reached this folder, you'll need to scroll down until you see the `mpv` folder. Double click that folder and inside you'll find `input.conf`. Open it up with an editor of your choice. I prefer visual studio code. Inside the `input.conf` editor add the following lines:

```
WHEEL_UP ignore
WHEEL_DOWN ignore
```

for a four-directional mouse:

```
WHEEL_RIGHT ignore 
WHEEL_LEFT ignore
```

Be sure to save your file afterwards.

[source](https://mpv.io/manual/master/)

Comment: Hi! Where would the OP find that file? Please see [answer] and take our [tour] to learn how to create answers that meet our community standards.

Comment: @Burgi I didn't think I'd have to explain since mpv is a custom video player that pretty much requires knowledge of where the input.conf file is to even use it. Anyways if you search for %appdata% you'll go to roaming/mpv/input.conf.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include that information. Several of your answers have not met the quality standard the community expects.

Comment: How am I supposed to comment and not answer when I can't get enough reputation to even comment? I'm only able to answer. I'd ask more questions if I was able to comment so it just doesn't make any sense why I'm forced to answer.

Comment: Please be patient, deleting your answer is worse than improving and waiting for upvotes. If you wish to talk about it please consider joining the chat room.

Comment: Which chatroom?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Comment: don't have enough reputation

Comment: The `input.conf` file didn't exist by default on my system. You also may want to include OS X and Linux in your configuration, sometimes input mapping is done differently.

Comment: For linux the file to create and or edit here is `~/.config/mpv/input.conf`